# Invalid syntax when define class decoder on imagine captionning

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, decoder

Here is my code when I define class decoder:

```
class decoder:
    # [batch_size, IMG_EMBED_SIZE] of CNN image features
    img_embeds = tf.placeholder('float32', [None, IMG_EMBED_SIZE])
    # [batch_size, time steps] of word ids
    sentences = tf.placeholder('int32', [None, None])
    .....
```

The problem is in this line:

```
    # flatten the ground truth token ids.
    flat_ground_truth = tf.reshape(sentences[:, 1:],[-1])
```

My error is:

```
File "<ipython-input-65-c9514f748a32>", line 57
    flat_ground_truth = tf.reshape(sentences[:, 1:],[-1]) 
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: always put ful error message (tarting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: often problem is in previous line - when someone forget closing `)`

Comment: this code is OK. It has to be missing `)` in previous line.

Comment: Yes, I found the missing ). Thank you.